# iPhone app Facebook Picture Upload

Tags: objective-c, iphone, facebook

I have another question. I want to upload a picture to Facebook. I have found some tutorials to do this.
I've read that you need to register your app first on facebook. Is this absolutly necessary to test the functionality?
My app isn't finished at all and I just want to test if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to do that, discard the fact if your app is ready or not. It's just a policy.

You can find everything you need about the Facebook API [here](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/)

I'ts quite easy so don't worry ;-)

Good luck!